# Add character to Out-File contents per line?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way using PowerShell Out-File that for each line inserted into the file to add a * at the beginning and end of each text in the Out-File?

Example:
Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath .\Process.txt

```
Test
Test1
```

Example Process.txt should contain:

```
*Test*
*Test1*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a collection, which is the output of most commands, you can loop through each element and format the output string. The example below uses the (`-f`) format operator to build the string.

```
$collection = @('test','test1','test2')
foreach ($entry in $collection) {
    "*{0}*" -f $entry | Out-File .\Process.txt -Append
}
```

The case above is simplistic. However, when outputting from a command, you typically get an object. You will need to tweak this to select the object properties you care about. If we adapt the above example for `Get-Process`, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($name in (Get-Process).Name) {
    "*{0}*" -f $name | Out-File .\Process.txt -Append
}
```

A conceptually similar but less verbose option with aliasing that only writes once to the output file:

```
Get-Process |% {"*$($_.Name)*"} | Out-File .\Process.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help